Changing Error Window Font Color in Visual Studio 2022
I am using the Ayu theme in Visual Studio 2022 and when I hover over the error in my code the window that pops up has horrible font/background color combo so I can't really read it. I went to Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors, but I'm not exactly sure which setting controls this color or if I am even able to change it.

I tried changing all color options in the Font and Colors section that looked similar to that color combo in the photo, but none of them worked. This is why I'm not even sure if I can change this color.

You can modify the colors for the editor tooltip. Here is an existing stack overflow answer.
You change Show settings for "Environment" to "Editor Tooltip".
